# What is the most efficient way of enjoying golf abroad in an EU country?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, sport-equipment

I am a keen golfer and and considering a holiday in an EU country specifically to spend 3-5 days golfing.

Is it more efficient (ease, cost, time) to bring my own equipment or is rental more suitable?  Are any countries particularly well suited to catering this?  Do you need permits etc?

I have heard that foreign rental can be

- Expensive
- Loaded with hidden extras
- Require significant deposit

Do any travellers have authoritative experience in this area?

Comment: Thanks @pnuts - that is exactly the kind of insight I was looking for.

Comment: Airlines' policies on sports equipment vary widely. The low-cost carriers are most likely to have high charges, while full service airlines are most likely to treat them as simply part of your baggage allowance.